# How to Hide and Show ArcGIS API ClusterLayer on Demand

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I followed [This API Tutorial](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers_point_clustering) to create Cluster Points on the map. Now I would like to have a function to hide them. I already tried like?

```
clusterLayer.hide();
```

but it didn't work! I also tried to bind the `clusterLayer` to a `GraphicsLayer` like below

```
  [var clayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();  
  clayer.add(clusterLayer);  
  clayer.hide();][1]
```

but still not working
After hours of working I find a sample on google at this [Demo doing](http://maps.esri.com/SP_DEMOS/crimemapper/index.html) the job of switching between Points and Cluster but it is supper complicated to me!
Can you please let me know how I can hide and show the cluster layer on demand?

Comment: Hi Behseini - I think you tried to link to a tutorial at the beginning of your question, but it seems like the link is missing - can you post the link to the tutorial you're trying to follow? Thanks!

Comment: @GavinR, Thanks for reminding, Post has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have, namely:

```
clusterLayer.hide();
```

.. should work! Here's an example (click the "hide" button I added - at the top): http://jsbin.com/qatihi/edit?html,js,output

Here is the code I added to the sample to make it work (in response to my button):

```
on(dom.byId("hide"), "click", function() {
    clusterLayer.hide();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GavinR, I know why it wasnt working for me now! I think I was putting the `clusterLayer.hide();` out of the scope of the `clusterLayer`. Thanks